# autoplay: true with jQuery flowslideshow when the window is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want:

autoplay: false when is width>900 in window size and  ,

autoplay: true when is width<900 & width>701 in window size and  ,

autoplay: false when is width<701 in window size

with jQuery flowslideshow and when the window is resized run this code

but notworking.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
var width = $(window).width();
if (width > 900) {
    $(function () {
        $(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {
            // enable "cross-fading" effect
            effect: 'fade',
            fadeOutSpeed: "slow",
            // start from the beginning after the last tab
            rotate: true,
            showMultiple: 5
            // use the slideshow plugin. It accepts its own configuration
        }).slideshow({ **autoplay: false**, clickable: false });
    });
}
else if (width < 900 & width > 701) {
    $(function () {
        $(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {
            // enable "cross-fading" effect
            effect: 'fade',
            fadeOutSpeed: "slow",
            // start from the beginning after the last tab
            rotate: true,
            showMultiple: 5
            // use the slideshow plugin. It accepts its own configuration
        }).slideshow({ **autoplay: true**, clickable: false });
    });
}
else (width < 701)
{
    $(function () {
        $(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {
            // enable "cross-fading" effect
            effect: 'fade',
            fadeOutSpeed: "slow",
            // start from the beginning after the last tab
            rotate: true,
            showMultiple: 5
            // use the slideshow plugin. It accepts its own configuration
        }).slideshow({ **autoplay: false**, clickable: false });
    });
}    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onResize event of the window does not always fire on page load, so the slideshow wouldn't autoplay in that case. It [does appear to fire on page load in ie9](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/window-resize-firing-on-page-load-in-ie9).

Also, this code would recreate the slideshow every time the page is resized - which is probably not what you want either.

You might be better binding the slideshow on page load, and then binding an event to resize that pauses / resumes the slide behaviour. Like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // detect window size and init slideshow here
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        // detect window size and pause or resume the slideshow
    });
});
```

Without seeing the docs for the slideshow you're using I can't point you in the direction of exactly how to modify the slideshow after it's initialised, but it should be possible if you follow the principle above.

(On a side note, to check the resize event is being triggered correctly, you could `console.log($(window).width())`)

If you need more help, consider posting a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the full example in it, and link to the docs for the slideshow plugin you're using.